# Could someone explain this behaviour with a bool function and an if statement?

Tags: c++, boolean

I'm attempting to create a function to check if a data type of `char[]`. If I don't include an extra `return false;`, the function returns unexpected behaviour.

Adding a `return false;` after the if statement inside my bool function, it works. I just want to understand why this happens.

The following code will execute `//contains` if the `contains_input` = "foo";

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool char_contains(char *input, const char *contain_input) {
    std::string contain_input_str = contain_input;
    std::string input_str = input;

    if (input_str.length() > 0
        && contain_input_str.length() > 0
        && input_str.find(contain_input) != std::string::npos) {

        return true;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char name[] = "Test!";

    if (char_contains(name, "foo")) {
        //contains
    }
}
```

, which is not the desired outcome, as 'Test!' does not contain 'foo'. Adding a `return false;` statement as follows will not execute `//contains`, which is expected behaviour:

```
bool char_contains(char *input, const char *contain_input) {
    std::string contain_input_str = contain_input;
    std::string input_str = input;

    if (input_str.length() > 0
        && contain_input_str.length() > 0
        && input_str.find(contain_input) != std::string::npos) {

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Finally, specifying `== true` will also return the expected behaviour:

```
char name[] = "Test!";

    if (char_contains(name, "foo") == true) {
        //contains
    }
```

Could someone please explain why this happens?
Thank you.

Comment: IIRC, Initializing `std::string` with a null pointer is UB. Your program will likely crash if `input` or `contain_input` are null. Better to init them like so: `std::string contain_input_str = contain_input ? contain_input : "";` and `std::string input_str = input ? input : "";`

Comment: Thank you! The program doesn't crash if it's null, but this is good practice. I will make sure to make those changes now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your function has a return-type of anything other than `void`, you need to make sure to always explicitly return a value from it, otherwise you'll invoke undefined behavior (in particular, the value returned from the function will be arbitrary).  So adding `return false;` to the end of your function is the correct thing to do; without it, you're returning *something*, but it's not defined what.

Btw double-check that you've enabled warnings on your compiler -- most compilers will generate a warning like `warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]` when they notice this type of error.